# Scan QR code (vcard) and save the contact on windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, qr-code, contacts, vcf-vcard

I am developing an app, but I have a problem with saving vcard as contact functionality. Here is how it works step by step:

1. Scan the QR Code (a vCard Data v2.1 http://www.printbusinesscards.com/marketing/qrcode/QR-Code-Quality-Standards-Test.php Test Case 12.02)
2. Now I store the dats in a string and I pass it to a new page:

   ````
   VERSION:2.1
   N:Standard;Joe;;;
   FN:Joe Standard12.02
   TEL:999-999-0001
   TEL;WORK:999-999-0002
   TEL;HOME:999-999-0003
   TEL;CELL:999-999-0004
   TEL;CELL;WORK:999-999-0005
   TEL;CELL,WORK:999-999-0006
   TEL;CELL;WORK;VOICE;MSG:999-999-0007
   TEL;CELL;WORK;VOICE;type=MSG:999-999-0008
   TEL;CELL;WORK;type=VOICE;type=MSG:999-999-0009
   END:VCARD)```
   ````
3. Now I have the problem. I want to save the string (vcard) as a contact. Is there a fast way, or I need to parse all the string?

(Actually should work as builtin windows phone bing qr readear.)

Answer (score 0):

I just parsed the string...I ound this but I didn't unederstand how to use, it seems wrong code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207024(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_SavingacontactfromaVCard